# Email Address and Phone Validation | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having some trouble getting validation to work for Email and Phone on an input field.

Basically I'm after validation on the email input when it is selected. Phone validation - mainly to check for numbers used.

I found [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and referenced that in my demo.

This is my first time to Reg Ex Validation and got a little confused so was hoping someone could help me on that front.

The phone validation is working however, I can't seem to figure out how to meet the requirements of the field when testing. It's also asking email as a required field.

Ultimately, a user has to input either a valid email or phone number so validation or error handling will need to be done for that too which I can do.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/775X2/33/)

Here is my jQuery:

```
var ebuForm = {

        init : function() {
            ebuForm.showInput();
            ebuForm.validatePhone();
        },

        showInput : function(e) {

            var radioInput = $("input[type='radio']"),
                emailRadio = $("input[value='email']");

            radioInput.change(function(){

                var emailInput = $('.email-input'),
                    phoneInput = $('.phone-input');

                if($(this).val() =="email") {
                    emailInput.show();
                    phoneInput.hide();
                    console.log('Email Enabled');
                } else {
                    emailInput.hide();
                    phoneInput.show();
                    console.log('Phone Enabled');
                }

            });
            emailRadio.prop('checked', true).trigger("change");
        },

        validatePhone : function() {
            $('#myform').validate({
                rules: {
                    phone: {
                        phoneUS: true,
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
                    alert('valid form');
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

};
$(function() {
    ebuForm.init();
});
```

Comment: So, you want to know the valid phone number format that should be entered? Or smething else ? :)

Comment: @hex494D49 The requirements are in the post

Answer (score 0):

**Working Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/775X2/56/**

Your HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    <div class="grid4">
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" tabindex="50" class="left" name="x" id="email" value="email" />
        <label for="email" class="left marginRight20">Email</label>
        <input type="radio" tabindex="60" class="left" name="x" id="phone" />
        <label for="phone" class="left">Phone</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" class="email-input" name="emailer" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <input type="text" class="phone-input" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" />
    </div>
</form>
<a href="http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation" target="_blank">Validation Documentation</a>
```

Some jQuery:

```
var ebuForm = {

    init: function () {
        ebuForm.showInput();
        ebuForm.validatePhone();
    },

    showInput: function (e) {

        var radioInput = $("input[type='radio']"),
            emailRadio = $("input[value='email']");

        radioInput.change(function () {

            var emailInput = $('.email-input'),
                phoneInput = $('.phone-input');

            if ($(this).val() == "email") {
                emailInput.show();
                phoneInput.hide();
                console.log('Email Enabled');
            } else {
                emailInput.hide();
                phoneInput.show();
                console.log('Phone Enabled');
            }

        });
        emailRadio.prop('checked', true).trigger("change");
    },

    validatePhone: function () {
        $('#myform').validate({
            rules: {
                phone: {
                    phoneUS: true,
                    required: true
                },
                emailer: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                alert('valid form');
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

};
$(function () {
    ebuForm.init();
});
```